# ddply summarise with Confidence interval?

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr, confidence-interval

I am trying to summarise my data with ddply, and I am trying to find a way I could summarise the data while reflecting the reliability.

Here is a desciption of my data set.

```
  BSTN ASTN  BSEC ASTN1 BSTN2 ASTN2 BSTN3 ASTN3 BSTN4 ASTN4 BSTN5 TFtime Ttime    ID
1 1001 1003 69551  1703  1703     0     0     0     0     0     0    399  2933 35404
2 1001 1006 69664  1703  1703     0     0     0     0     0     0    399  2284 35405
3 1001 1701 66606  1703  1703     0     0     0     0     0     0    118  1750 35406
4 1001 1701 66600  1703  1703     0     0     0     0     0     0    118  1750 35406
5 1001 1701 66601  1703  1703     0     0     0     0     0     0    118  1750 35406
6 1001 1703 69434     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0      0  1005 35407
```

What I would like as my output is a to summarise the values of Ttime and TFtime grouped by "ASTN"s and  "BSTN"s.

**For the mean values of "Ttime" and "TFtime" I would like to reflect the confidence interval 95%.** So calculate the mean values of "Ttime" and "TFtime"s within the 95% boundary. **How would I do this process with ddply if there are multiple combinations of BSTN~ASTNs.**

below is the code I used and wish to revise.

```
Routetable<-ddply(A,c(.(BSTN),.(ASTN1),.(BSTN2),.(ASTN2),.(BSTN3),.(ASTN3),.(BSTN4),.(ASTN4),.(BSTN5),.(ASTN)), 
                    summarise, count=length(BSTN),mean=mean(Ttime),TFtimemean=mean(TFtime))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**updated answer**

I'm not sure, but I guess what you actually want to do is filter all values that are larger / smaller than `mean(x) -/+ 2*sd(x)` and this by each group. The following approach would do that. In the case of `ggplot2`s Diamond data set it keeps about 97% of all values and just removes the extremes.

```r
library(tidyverse)

diamonds %>% 
  group_by(cut, color) %>% 
  mutate(across(c(x,y,z),
                list(low = ~ mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE) - 2 * sd(.x, na.rm = TRUE),
                     high = ~ mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE) + 2 * sd(.x, na.rm = TRUE))
                )
         ) %>% 
  filter(x >= x_low & x <= x_high,
         y >= x_low & y <= y_high,
         z >= z_low & z <= z_high)
#> # A tibble: 52,299 x 16
#> # Groups:   cut, color [35]
#>    carat cut   color clarity depth table price     x     y     z x_low x_high
#>    <dbl> <ord> <ord> <ord>   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
#>  1 0.23  Ideal E     SI2      61.5    55   326  3.95  3.98  2.43  3.51   6.92
#>  2 0.21  Prem~ E     SI1      59.8    61   326  3.89  3.84  2.31  3.52   7.65
#>  3 0.290 Prem~ I     VS2      62.4    58   334  4.2   4.23  2.63  3.86   9.12
#>  4 0.31  Good  J     SI2      63.3    58   335  4.34  4.35  2.75  4.14   8.62
#>  5 0.24  Very~ I     VVS1     62.3    57   336  3.95  3.98  2.47  3.92   8.62
#>  6 0.26  Very~ H     SI1      61.9    55   337  4.07  4.11  2.53  3.66   8.30
#>  7 0.23  Very~ H     VS1      59.4    61   338  4     4.05  2.39  3.66   8.30
#>  8 0.3   Good  J     SI1      64      55   339  4.25  4.28  2.73  4.14   8.62
#>  9 0.23  Ideal J     VS1      62.8    56   340  3.93  3.9   2.46  3.88   8.76
#> 10 0.31  Ideal J     SI2      62.2    54   344  4.35  4.37  2.71  3.88   8.76
#> # ... with 52,289 more rows, and 4 more variables: y_low <dbl>, y_high <dbl>,
#> #   z_low <dbl>, z_high <dbl>
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

**old answer**

With better example data we could achieve a more programmatic approach. As example I use `ggplot2`s `diamonds` dataset. See my comments in the code below.

```r
library(tidyverse)

diamonds %>% 
  # set up your groups
  nest_by(cut, color) %>%  
  # define in `across` for which variables you want means and conf int to be calculated 
  mutate(ttest = list(summarise(data, across(c(x,y,z), 
                                          ~ broom::tidy(t.test(.x))))),
         ttest = list(unpack(ttest, c(x, y, z), names_sep = "_") %>% 
   # select only the estimates and conf intervalls                          
                        select(contains("estimate"), contains("conf")))) %>% 
  unnest(ttest)
#> # A tibble: 35 x 12
#> # Groups:   cut, color [35]
#>    cut   color      data x_estimate y_estimate z_estimate x_conf.low x_conf.high
#>    <ord> <ord> <list<tb>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>       <dbl>
#>  1 Fair  D     [163 × 8]       6.02       5.96       3.84       5.89        6.15
#>  2 Fair  E     [224 × 8]       5.91       5.86       3.72       5.80        6.02
#>  3 Fair  F     [312 × 8]       5.99       5.93       3.79       5.89        6.09
#>  4 Fair  G     [314 × 8]       6.17       6.11       3.96       6.06        6.28
#>  5 Fair  H     [303 × 8]       6.58       6.50       4.22       6.47        6.69
#>  6 Fair  I     [175 × 8]       6.56       6.49       4.19       6.43        6.70
#>  7 Fair  J     [119 × 8]       6.75       6.68       4.32       6.55        6.95
#>  8 Good  D     [662 × 8]       5.62       5.63       3.50       5.55        5.69
#>  9 Good  E     [933 × 8]       5.62       5.63       3.50       5.56        5.68
#> 10 Good  F     [909 × 8]       5.69       5.71       3.54       5.63        5.76
#> # … with 25 more rows, and 4 more variables: y_conf.low <dbl>,
#> #   y_conf.high <dbl>, z_conf.low <dbl>, z_conf.high <dbl>
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

If you want to filter observations based on the confidence iIntervalls of the means you can adjust my approach above as follows. Note that this is not the same as filtering the top and bottom 2.5 % of each variable, you will loose a lot of data.

```r
library(tidyverse)

diamonds %>% 
  nest_by(cut, color) %>% 
  mutate(ttest = summarise(data, across(c(x,y,z), 
                                             ~ broom::tidy(t.test(.x)))) %>% 
         unpack(c(x,y,z), names_sep = "_")) %>% 
  unpack(ttest) %>% 
  select(cut, color, data, contains("estimate"), contains("conf")) %>% 
  rowwise(cut, color) %>% 
  mutate(data = list(filter(data,
                       x >= x_conf.low & x <= x_conf.high,
                       y >= x_conf.low & y <= y_conf.high,
                       z >= z_conf.low & z <= z_conf.high))) %>% 
  unnest(data)
#> # A tibble: 322 x 19
#> # Groups:   cut, color [30]
#>    cut   color carat clarity depth table price     x     y     z x_estimate
#>    <ord> <ord> <dbl> <ord>   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>
#>  1 Fair  D      0.91 SI2      62.5    66  3079  6.08  6.01  3.78       6.02
#>  2 Fair  D      0.9  SI2      65.7    60  3205  5.98  5.93  3.91       6.02
#>  3 Fair  D      0.9  SI2      64.7    59  3205  6.09  5.99  3.91       6.02
#>  4 Fair  D      0.95 SI2      64.4    60  3384  6.06  6.02  3.89       6.02
#>  5 Fair  D      0.9  SI2      64.9    57  3473  6.03  5.98  3.9        6.02
#>  6 Fair  D      0.9  SI2      64.5    61  3473  6.1   6     3.9        6.02
#>  7 Fair  D      0.9  SI1      64.5    61  3689  6.05  6.01  3.89       6.02
#>  8 Fair  D      0.91 SI1      64.7    61  3730  6.06  5.99  3.9        6.02
#>  9 Fair  D      0.9  SI2      64.6    59  3847  6.04  6.01  3.89       6.02
#> 10 Fair  D      0.91 SI1      64.4    60  3855  6.08  6.04  3.9        6.02
#> # ... with 312 more rows, and 8 more variables: y_estimate <dbl>,
#> #   z_estimate <dbl>, x_conf.low <dbl>, x_conf.high <dbl>, y_conf.low <dbl>,
#> #   y_conf.high <dbl>, z_conf.low <dbl>, z_conf.high <dbl>
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. So if im correct, below are the filetered results?. What I want as my final output is cut down datas that are not in the CI. I want to cut down these data  and summarise them  based on BSTN and ASTNs. There are some values that are way bigger or way smaller compared to the average time which is why i want to filter

Comment: What I want as my final output is to eliminate datas that are not in the Upper and Lower boundaries, then summarise the data with average Ttime and TFtime.

Comment: Maybe my updated answer solves your problem. I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Using package `dplyr` (which is more up-to-date than `plyr`) you can write as follows. "LB" and "UB" stand for "Lower Bound" and "Upper Bound" respectively.

```
library(dplyr)

A %>% 
  group_by(across(starts_with("BSTN") | starts_with("ASTN"))) %>% 
  summarise(
    count = n(),
    mean_Ttime = mean(Ttime),
    mean_TFtime = mean(TFtime),
    LB_Ttime = mean_Ttime - qnorm(0.975) * sd(Ttime) / sqrt(count),
    UB_Ttime = mean_Ttime + qnorm(0.975) * sd(Ttime) / sqrt(count),
    LB_TFtime = mean_TFtime - qnorm(0.975) * sd(TFtime) / sqrt(count),
    UB_TFtime = mean_TFtime + qnorm(0.975) * sd(TFtime) / sqrt(count)
  )
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 17
# Groups:   BSTN, BSTN2, BSTN3, BSTN4, BSTN5, ASTN, ASTN1, ASTN2, ASTN3 [4]
#    BSTN BSTN2 BSTN3 BSTN4 BSTN5  ASTN ASTN1 ASTN2 ASTN3 ASTN4 count mean_Ttime mean_TFtime LB_Ttime UB_Ttime LB_TFtime UB_TFtime
#   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>      <dbl>       <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
# 1  1001     0     0     0     0  1703     0     0     0     0     1       1005           0       NA       NA        NA        NA
# 2  1001  1703     0     0     0  1003  1703     0     0     0     1       2933         399       NA       NA        NA        NA
# 3  1001  1703     0     0     0  1006  1703     0     0     0     1       2284         399       NA       NA        NA        NA
# 4  1001  1703     0     0     0  1701  1703     0     0     0     3       1750         118     1750     1750       118       118
```

With this sample data we obtain several NAs because the `count` of the group is 1 in those cases, but when you have larger datasets it's rare that you will obtain them.

Comment: thank you!! sorry for the late response,  So are the final output rows that are in the confidence interval boundary?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean exactly? I don't understand your question

Comment: Sorry for the bad explanation. So are the remaning datas after applying this code are in the boundary of 0.975%? I want to eliminate datas that have travel time and transfer time that are  in the confiedence interval

Comment: These are not your original rows anymore. They are a summary of your original rows, grouped by all the `BSTN` and `ASTN` variables.

Comment: @Yun Hynsoo: Do you want to remove observations that are lower/higher than the confidence intervall of the **means** or do you just want to cut the top 2.5 % of your data? There is a big difference and for the latter we do not need to calculate the confidence Intervalls of the means. If you delete observations based on the CI of the means you will loose a lot of data.

Comment: See may updated answer below, but I doubt that this is what you are looking for,

Comment: @RicS What I want as my final output is to eliminate datas that are not in the Upper and Lower boundaries, then summarise the data with average Ttime and TFtime. sorry for my poor explanation